# Value is not present in email contact form 7

Tags: wordpress

enter image description here  [image]I have used contact form 7 with Contact Form 7 Multi-Step Forms plugin my contact form is a two-step form

As I save the first form it displays the correct format on email 
but as I add `[multistep "1-2-http:www.mysite.com/]` to end of the form it combined two form that is what I want.

But After combining it send's email incorrect format like

```
Title   : [title]
First Name  : [FirstName]
Last Name  : [LastName]
Address  : [address]
Address  : [address2]
Town : [town]
```

and so on

Not get the value because in first form all the tags are visible like `[title] [FirstName] [address] [town]` ... but not in form two

I guess this is the reason why value is not coming

Please help 
[image]

Comment: What you get in the second form ?

Comment: Add screenshot of form settings.

Comment: its an paypal payemt link with buy now button

Comment: Check both the screen shot after two I recieved the email in incorrect format